# Is it possible to change the side of component and existing track and via in altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layers

almost everything is in title. 
I have a existing routing track and via. I would like to change side of all component.
It's a 4 layer, so, in a perfect world :
top component goes to bottom layer

- top track to bottom layer
- bottom track to top layer
- ground layer does nothing
- and mid layer with routing is flipped.

for the the last 2 options, I'll understand if this is not automated.

Does an automatic option exist for this kind of needs ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: When you move a component from top to bottom, the footprint/pinout is mirrored, so it will not connect properly to the tracks that you moved to from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Edit -> Move -> Flip Selection (shortcut M I).
It swaps all selected objects between Top and Bottom and mirrors objects in the inner layers.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: I just discovered that I can push on L when grab all my component to do the same task...